# Хекс-просмоторщик на C++

Tags: windows, c++

Требуется написать Хекс-просмоторщик на С++. По типу аналога, как в Тотале, когда выбирается файл, потом "F3", потом "3" - получаем Хекс вид.

В общем, выглядеть должно без наворотов. Форма. Окно проводника. Выбираем файл. Жмём, например, кнопульку "Хекс код" - получаем новую форму с хексом. Закрываем её. Всё.

Вопрос. Я в C++ - дилетант. Знаю только синтаксис и базовые принципы ООП. Никогда не углублялся в суть, а тут пришлось. Подскажите, какой проект создавать для написания данного приложения. Я так понимаю, что надо почитать тему MFC?

Answer (score 1):

1. Чтобы встроиться в проводник, нужно работать с интерфейсом [IShellFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775075(v=vs.85).aspx).
2. Для простейшего приложения Windows на C++, подойдут либо Forms (CLI), либо MFC, либо WTL.

Читать здесь: [приступая к работе с Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualc/ee340952.aspx).